# How do you use /title properly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you use /title? I used it like this

```
/title @a title {text:"you're fighting the castle",bold:true,italic:true,color:red}"
```

and it gave me this error

> [10:51:17] Invalid json: malformed JSON at line 1 column 3

I'm trying to make something and I've been stuck for a while so if anyone knows please help me!!!

Comment: Only tag the game you are talking about please.  I assume it's just Minecraft, and not *Minecraft, Diablo 3, Majoras Mask, and Clash of Clans.*

Comment: Try putting your Strings in double quotes: `{"text":"you're fighting the castle","bold":true,"italic":true,"color":"red"}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command with proper [JSON formatting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text):

```
/title @a title {"text":"you're fighting the castle","color":"red","bold":true,"italic":true}
```

You were missing quotation marks around text, color, red, bold, and italic.  You also have a single quotation mark at the very end which shouldn't be there.

I recommend using a JSON generator.  This makes it easy as you don't have to know JSON formatting.

One example which can do titles: https://www.minecraftjson.com/